# Not able to access Assets file under dynamic module

Tags: android, dynamic-delivery

I am working with android applications.
So far I had some files on my assets which I was able to access using

```
context.getAssets().open(fileName)
```

Now I am trying to integrate a dynamic on demand module with some of app features. And I moved some of my assets file from app module to dynamic module asset folder as those are only needed with dynamic features.
All the features are working after downloading on demand module using `SplitInstallManager`
But I am not getting the asset file using above code.

Do we need to access the assets same way for app module. Or there is other option for on demand module?

When I analyze the aab file from android studio, I see that assets folder and files are included with on demand module. I am testing by using internal app sharing of google play.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm too stuck with the same use case.